# Python's orphaned parser commands expr, st2list, sequence2st, compilest: are there any replacements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I have (I might even say I inherited it) a superb curve fitting library entirely written in Python. It worked pretty well until 3.10 was released. Then the module **parser** was deprecated and, obviously, my much-loved library stopped working. It all boils down to four parser commands only: **expr, st2list, sequence2st** and **compilest**, which appear in just a few lines (listed in their order of appearance, but not necessarily one right after the other):

```
st = parser.expr(stringToConvert)
stList = parser.st2list(st)
st = parser.sequence2st(stList)
self.userFunctionCodeObject  = parser.compilest(st)
```

I never knew exactly what **parser** did, and, needless to say, I'm completely lost as to what to do now to get my library working again. I can't write my own parser commands because I don't know what the deprecated commands did. Also, I don't know what the parameters in the calls (stringToConvert, st, stList) are, type-wise, nor how they look like. I wish I could tell, but the execution aborts before any debug can be made since **parser** can't be imported. I tried (and have been trying) Google, but the more I delve into this matter, the more confused I get.

Any hints? I'm using Windows 11 and Python 3.10.8-64 bit. Thanks!

**PS:**
Indeed, there is just 1 line in the middle of those commands. Here it is the sequence as it appears in the code:

```
# convert integer use such as (3/2) into floats such as (3.0/2.0)
st = parser.expr(stringToConvert)
stList = parser.st2list(st)
stList = self.RecursivelyConvertIntStringsToFloatStrings(stList)
st = parser.sequence2st(stList)

# later evals re-use this compiled code for improved performance
# in EvaluateCachedData() methods

self.userFunctionCodeObject  = parser.compilest(st)
```

It's an internal function. I might try to check what it does.

Comment: Scavenge and repackage the library out of a 3.9 install and continue to be obvivious as to what exactly it does.

Comment: @tripleee It's probably written in C or C++, in which case I wouldn't know what to do. It would be more efficient to install a separate version of Python 3.9 or even go back to it. But, frankly, this is not a long-term solution. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like just a really overcomplicated way of writing

```
self.userFunctionCodeObject = compile(stringToConvert, 'file.py', 'eval')
```

Your code builds an ST object representing the concrete syntax tree for an expression, converts the ST object to a nested list representation, converts that representation *back* to an ST object, then compiles it into a code object. `compile` can compile expressions into code objects directly.

The real problem is dealing with any transformations the code does to `stList` before rebuilding an ST object. You said these lines aren't directly after each other, so I'm guessing you left out some modifications to `stList` in the middle. If so, you're not going to be able to just call `compile` and be done with it.

If the code modified `stList` before rebuilding the ST object, you're going to have to read that code, understand the modifications it performs, and figure out how to perform the corresponding modifications on an abstract syntax tree created with the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module:

```
abstract_tree = ast.parse(stringToConvert, mode='eval')
# do something to abstract_tree
self.userFunctionCodeObject = compile(abstract_tree, 'file.py', 'eval')
```

Comment: To what library does ```compile()``` belong? To **ast**?

Comment: @FaustoArinosBarbuto: It's a built-in.

Comment: Please read the PS in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: @FaustoArinosBarbuto: I can't see what `self.RecursivelyConvertIntStringsToFloatStrings` does, but assuming it transforms int literals to float literals, you'd want to use a [`NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) with a `visit_Constant` method that replaces int constants with float constants, then use [`fix_missing_locations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.fix_missing_locations) to fill in line and column information before compiling the AST.

Comment: That said, you *might* be able to get away with just `compile`-ing the string directly and not bothering with any AST transformations. The comments in the source code suggest this transformation was likely written to deal with Python 2 integer division behavior, which isn't an issue on Python 3.

Comment: Gee, the plot thickens. ;-) Thanks for your help. I will see what I can do with all that info. It's pretty sad that Python developers change/deprecate libraries in such a way that no one can port legacy code in a straightforward way. I always hoped that I could replace those orphaned commands with their corresponding ones in the new library (ast???), but that seems to be impossible. My lack of understanding about those commands doesn't help, either, but conversion examples should exist out there in the internet. It's  really a frustrating state of things.

Comment: The background is that some librarier had gone unmaintained for many years, and none of the Python core developers felt like _they_ understood how they worked, either. Maybe read about the "Dead Batteries" project ([PEP-594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/)).