# How to convert those deprecated parse commands to Python 3.10?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing

I have a couple of lines written with old Python 2.7's `parser` commands that don't seem to have equivalents in Python > 3.10. They are:

```
st = parser.expr(stringToConvert)
tup = st.totuple()
```

where `stringToConvert` is a `<type 'unicode'>` string such as, for example:

`a5*X**5 + a4*X**4 + a3*X**3 + a2*X**2 + a1*X + a0 + log(5.0)`

In Python 2.7, the two lines up above yield something like:

```
(258, (332, (306, (310, (311, (312, (313, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (321, (322, (323,
(324, (325, (1, 'a5'))))), (16, '*'), (322, (323, (324, (325, (1, 'X'))), (35, '**'),
(322, (323, (324, (325, (2, '5')))))))), (14, '+'), (321, (322, (323, (324, (325, 
(1, 'a4'))))), (16, '*'), (322, (323, (324, (325, (1, 'X'))), (35, '**'), (322, (323, 
(324, (325, (2, '4')))))))), (14, '+'), (321, (322, (323, (324, (325, (1, 'a3'))))),
(16, '*'), (322, (323, (324, (325, (1, 'X'))), (35, '**'), (322, (323, (324, (325, 
(2, '3')))))))), (14, '+'), (321, (322, (323, (324, (325, (1, 'a2'))))), (16, '*'), 
(322, (323, (324, (325, (1, 'X'))), (35, '**'), (322, (323, (324, (325, (2, '2')))))))), 
(14, '+'), (321, (322, (323, (324, (325, (1, 'a1'))))), (16, '*'), (322, (323, (324, 
(325, (1, 'X')))))), (14, '+'), (321, (322, (323, (324, (325, (1, 'a0')))))), (14, '+'),
(321, (322, (323, (324, (325, (1, 'log')), (327, (7, '('), (335, (336, (306, (310, (311, 
(312, (313, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (321, (322, (323, (324, (325, (2, 
'5.0')))))))))))))))))), (8, ')'))))))))))))))))), (4, ''), (4, ''), (0, ''))
```

I've been stuck with these two lines for days now. I have no idea what the convoluted tuple above is all about nor to what it is good for, but the code needs it. All I know is that `parser` is now defunct and so far I've been unable to get along with the new parser(?). The `<type 'unicode'>` thing may also pose an extra problem, as it is also deprecated (or isn't it?). Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I see you're still working on [that thing from earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75423388/pythons-orphaned-parser-commands-expr-st2list-sequence2st-compilest-are-the). Don't bother trying to force your code to produce that giant nested tuple. It's too deeply tied to the old parser implementation - it doesn't actually mean anything to the new parser. You'd basically have to completely reimplement Python's entire parser to get this to work, *and* an unparser to convert back to Python source code afterward.

Comment: Reimplementing `self.RecursivelyConvertIntStringsToFloatStrings(stList)` to work on an AST is *far, far* easier than trying to reimplement Python's whole parser just so you can reuse the old `self.RecursivelyConvertIntStringsToFloatStrings` implementation.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, it's the same project. I put it aside for a few days while I was working on something else but now I'm back to it. I guess I figured out how to handle "that thing from earlier", but then I got stuck a bit above in the code (those 2 lines) and found out that that odd-looking tupple "tup" is essential to whatever comes next in the script. Unfortunately, the more I google the more I get confused. It seems that `parser` is gone forever and no replacements were left in place. I may have to rewrite the whole thing with my less-than-mediocre programming skills (at that level).

Comment: @user2357112, as for that odd-looking tuple, the script I'm working on has a function tailored to deal with it. Once the tuple is created, it is passed to the said function and _presto_! It returns whatever the code needs. All I need is the tuple. Needless to say, I googled for the source of `totuple()` but even loose references to `totuple()` are scarce - let alone a Python source code.

Comment: "Once the tuple is created, it is passed to the said function and *presto*! It returns whatever the code needs." - perhaps, but that function will almost certainly rely on the `parser` module too, or whatever that function's output is used for will depend on the `parser` module. And even if it doesn't...

Comment: The old parser implementation is *thousands of lines of code*, and you can't even reuse any of that, because the Python grammar has evolved past what the underlying algorithm can support. The new parser is thousands of lines of *completely incompatible* code. You're going to have to maintain your own fork of that, and get it to produce output like the old parser, and track down weird bugs when your fork doesn't quite parse things the way it's supposed to, or doesn't quite produce the right tuples (that you don't understand anyway).

Comment: It's almost certainly going to be easier to change the code that uses `tup` to work with an AST than to put such massive effort into forking, overhauling, and maintaining a fork of Python's parser.

Comment: (And if it turns out your code is doing something that really needs a concrete syntax tree instead of an abstract syntax tree, the best approach is probably going to be to use a 3rd-party CST library, even if that means rewriting your code to use a different CST representation. [LibCST](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) would be one option, though I don't know how good it is.)

Comment: @user2357112, thanks for the invaluable insights you've provided on this matter. As for the function that picks the tuple up and returns whatever the code needs, no, it has no calls to `parser` whatsoever. It uses ordinary, plain silly Python syntax only. As for the rest, I do agree with you. Not only the old `totuple()` certainly has 1000s of lines - it certainly calls other `parser` functions whose functioning I don't understand also and am not willing to tackle. I'll see what I can do, but at this point the only solution I envision is to keep a copy of Python 2.7 on my computer - forever.